# How to access array of characters in different ways

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I've a function using pointer arithmetic to print out all character inside char*:

```
void printCharArray(char* c,int n)
{
    for (char*p=c+n-1; n; n--) 
        cout << *p--;
}
```

The above code works but I want to try another way which is not working:

```
void printCharArray(char* c,int n)
{
    char *p = &c [n - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << *--p;
}
```

The strange behavior is that if I change `char *p = &c [n - 1];` to `char *p = &c [n];` then it's working but I expect `&c [n - 1]` equal to the last character inside the char array but not `&c[n]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--p;` is equivalent to `p = p - 1; p;`
`p--;` is equivalent to `auto tmp = p; p = p - 1; tmp`

in other words

```
void printCharArray(char* c,int n)
{
    for (char*p=c+n-1; n; n--) 
        cout << *p--;
}
```

this will display `*p`, `*(p - 1)`, ..., `*(p - n)`

```
void printCharArray(char* c,int n)
{
    char *p = &c [n - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << *--p;
}
```

this will display `*(p - 1)`, `*(p - 2)`, ..., `*(p - (n+1))`

Comment: +1, "*--p" expression in words is "decrease the address of p to 1, and then take a value of that address". Therefore you'll got "c[n-2]" chatacter as first in output.